# How to change column default value in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql5.5.

I have a table `media__gallery` and I want change the default value of the column `default_format` from `'NO'` to `'YES'`, but when I write the query and run through command line nothing is updated.

My Query :

```
ALTER TABLE `media__gallery` CHANGE `default_format` `default_format` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NULL DEFAULT 'YES';
```

MySql Table :

```
mysql> desc media__gallery;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| context        | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| default_format | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| enabled        | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id    | int(11)      | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't think that existing values got to be updated with that. Have you tried inserting new values without specifying the default_format field so you can check it works?. Just do the alter table and then try the obligatory update.

Comment: Your query is fine. But if you're expecting that somehow __existing__ values will be updated to `YES` - you're not correct.

Comment: Thanks for comment @AlmaDo , You are right , My query is fine and this working when I again run desc media__gallery and this is updated show Yes.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE media_gallery
ALTER COLUMN default_format SET DEFAULT 'YES'
```

This should do the trick.

Look [here (W3Schools - SQL DEFAULT constraint)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp) for more information .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `media__gallery`
CHANGE COLUMN `default_format` `default_format` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT 'YES'
```

**The old values must be set manually**

```
UPDATE `media__gallery` SET `default_format`='YES' WHERE  `default_format`='NO'
```